# Compare two files and find diff to output to new file(faster way)

Tags: python

I am reading two files and comparing two to find lines that greylist_previous not having it but greylist_current having and output to the new file. I am trying to figure out the faster way to process it. If you guys has better solution please reply. Thank you.

```
prev_f = open('greylist_prev.txt')
current_f=open('greylist_current.txt')
greylist_f=open('greylist.txt','w')

prev_line = prev_f.readlines()
greylist=[]
total_line=sum(1 for line in open('greylist_current.txt'))

if total_line < 10:
  greylist_f.write("\n")


else:
   for current_line in current_f:
          if current_line not in prev_line:
                greylist.append(current_line)


for line in greylist:
   greylist_f.write("%s" %line)


prev_f.close()
current_f.close()
greylist_f.close()
```

is it same result as linux command

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{_1[$1]++;next}!_1[$1]' greylist_prev.txt greylist_current.txt > greylist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `sort` both input files, and `join` them later. This avoids putting all keys into main memory (in case the files are large), and its time complexity depends on the sort tasks -- normally `O(n log n)`. For example, for files A and B:

```
file A | file B
1,foo  | 1,bar
2,fooo | 3,baar
       | 4,gee
```

You may run:

```
$ join -v 2 -t ',' <(sort -t ',' a.txt) <(sort -t ',' b.txt)
3,baar
4,gee
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines are the culprit:

```
for current_line in current_f:
     if current_line not in prev_line:
           greylist.append(current_line)
```

Looking for items in a large list is slow relative to looking for items in a dictionary. This speed comes at the expense of memory. You can speed your code up by storing the lines of the greylist_prev.txt file in a dictionary instead of a list.

Open the file:

```
file = open('greylist_prev.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
```

Create a dict, and store the items in file as keys:

```
d = {}
for i in file:
    d[i] = ''
```

Then modify the culprit lines to:

```
else:
   for current_line in current_f:
          if current_line not in d:
                greylist.append(current_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/difflib.html) module. According to the docs:

> This module provides classes and functions for comparing sequences. It can be used for example, for comparing files, and can produce difference information in various formats, including HTML and context and unified diffs. For comparing directories and files, see also, the filecmp module.

**difflib.Differ**  is what you're looking for.

> This is a class for comparing sequences of lines of text, and producing human-readable differences or deltas. Differ uses SequenceMatcher both to compare sequences of lines, and to compare sequences of characters within similar (near-matching) lines.